# How to prevent constructor call in Lambda function test?

Tags: javascript, lambda, sinon, serverless

I have following class:

```
class Connection {
    constructor() {
        Log.debug('Constructor called!');
        // Connect to DB
    }
}
module.exports = Connection;
```

This class is used in Lambda function:

```
const Connection = require('Connection');

const connection = new Connection();

module.exports.endpoint = (event, context, callback) => {
    // This will allow us to freeze open connections to a database
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    // CODE HERE
}
```

The code above works well once deployed locally or to AWS.

Now, I have a test that mocks DB calls fine. However, because of the constructor there are two side effects:

- the test actually connects to DB (which is not required and unwanted while running a test)
- once connection is established test waits for the connection to be closed

This is the beginning of my test (which actually calls `Connection()`)

```
const mochaPlugin = require('serverless-mocha-plugin');

const { expect } = mochaPlugin.chai;

const sinon = require('sinon');

const wrapped = mochaPlugin.getWrapper('functionName', '/path/lambda.js', 'endpoint');

// Actual code starts below...
```

I did try to use `sinon` and stub constructor call to `Connection` class with no luck as basically the line `mochaPlugin.getWrapper...` creates the connection.

How can I prevent constructor call? Is three a nice and clean way to stub it?

Additional information: I'm running my test with `sls invoke test`

Comment: If you can still change to `jest` instead of `mocha` + `sinon`, it'd be easier.

Comment: I'll need to investigate this. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no answer yet... this will work:

- add an environment variable: `IS_LOCAL = true`

Then in Connection class check if it is set and modify constructor to skip connection to DB.

```
constructor() {
    if (!process.env.IS_LOCAL) {
        // Connect to DB
    }
}
```

This way there won't be any need to change the code of the test and the actual lambda function! The connection class can be re-used elsewhere too.